# "Se dice" versus "dicen que"

Tags: coloquialismos

Entiendo las dos frases.

¿se utilice " se dice" más en una redacción que "dicen que" ?

Creo que es correcto y la última es más informal. ¿Verdad?

Comment: It's "¿se utiliza...?" instead of "¿se utilice.. ?". "Dicen que" and "Se dice" are mostly the same. The only difference is that you may know the subject in the first place, who exactly say whathever. "Dicen que" is not more informal.

Comment: Yes, the meaning is the same but not the formality. You are more likely to hear dicen que in every day speech, and se dice is more formal contexts. "Dicen que el muchacho está muy enfermo." I would have a hard time imagining - in every day speech - someone saying to me in a conversation: "Se dice que el muchacho está muy enfermo". Unless it were something like: Se dice por ahí etc. Of course, you can see the answer below from ominous for this: también suena más formal ya que sólo puede significar una cosa y no se presta a interpretación como la otra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas son impersonales, es decir, no hablas de nadie en específico. Sin embargo, "dicen que" puede tomar dos significados según el contexto: uno impersonal y otro refiriéndose a "ellos" (They say that...).

**DICEN QUE**

Por ejemplo, puede ser impersonal:

> Dicen que en la noche asustan.

¿Quiénes lo dicen? No sé, ellos, pero no sé con exactitud quiénes. Por eso estoy generalizando y realmente no me refiero a "alguien" en particular.

Pero también puede ser utilizado para referirse a alguien en específico:

> Los niños dicen que en la noche asustan.

¿Quiénes lo dicen? Los niños.

**SE DICE**

Mientras que "Se dice" no logra tener este segundo significado como el anterior. Ya que es únicamente impersonal y al usarlo estás generalizando sí o sí. Por eso, es más común que se use de esta forma y también suena más formal ya que sólo puede significar una cosa y no se presta a interpretación como la otra.

> Se dice que en las noches asustan.

¿Pero quién lo dice? No sé, estoy generalizando.